# Probability question autocorrelation function

Tags: probability

Let $V_1$,$V_2$, $r$ be independent random variables, where $V_1$, $V_2$ are Gausian with the same distribution and $r$ is uniformly distributed in $[0,1]$ if

$$X(t)=V_2 I(r \geqslant t)+V_1 I(r<t)$$

a)find the mean of this process:

For the expectation I have the following:

$\mathbb{E}X(t)=μ(1-t)+μ t=μ$

b) find the autocorrelation function of this process

$R(t,s)=\mathbb{E}( X(t) X(s) )$

I have simplified this as much as I can, I don't know why I can't copy and paste what I have done, when I try only some of it appears. I have simplified it down to $\sigma^2$ * probability of union of the indicator functions and a similar expression with the mean.

Comment: The autocorrelation function R of the process X is not defined by R(t,s)=E(X(t)X(s)).

Comment: @Didier The definition of the autocorrelation function adopted in signal processing is as stated by OP (see [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autocorrelation#Signal_processing)), and is different from conventional definition adopted in statistics.

Comment: @Sasha: Thanks, nice to know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $\mu$ denote mean of Gaussians $\mu = \mathbb{E}(V_1)=\mathbb{E}(V_2)$.
$$ \begin{eqnarray}
   \mathbb{E}\left( X(t) \right) &=& \mathbb{E}\left( V_2 I(R \geqslant t) + V_1 I(R<t) \right) \stackrel{\text{independence}}{=} \mathbb{E}(V_2) \mathbb{P}( R \geqslant t) + 
 \mathbb{E}(V_1) \mathbb{P}( R < t) \\ &=& \mu \left(  \underbrace{\mathbb{P}( R \geqslant t) + \mathbb{P}( R < t)}_{\begin{array}{c}\text{sum of probabilities of}\\ \text{ complementary events}\end{array}}\right) = \mu
\end{eqnarray}
$$
As to the autocorrelation function:
$$\begin{eqnarray}
  \mathbb{E}\left( X(t) X(s)\right) &=& \mathbb{E}(\mathbb{V_2^2}) \mathbb{E}\left(I(R \geqslant t)I(R \geqslant s)\right) \\ &+& \mathbb{E}(\mathbb{V_1 V_2}) \left( \mathbb{E}\left(I(R \geqslant t)I(R < s)\right)  + \mathbb{E}\left(I(R < t)I(r \geqslant s)\right) \right) \\ &+& \mathbb{E}(V_1^2) \mathbb{E}(I(R>t)I(R>s)) 
\end{eqnarray}
$$
Now expectations of product of indicator functions is done by converting them to probabilities and doing some logic:
$$\mathbb{E}\left(I(R \geqslant t)I(R \geqslant s)\right) = \mathbb{P}(R \geqslant t, R\geqslant s) = \mathbb{P}(R \geqslant \max(t,s))$$ 
$$\mathbb{E}\left(I(R\geqslant t) I(R<s)\right) = \mathbb{P}(s > R\geqslant t)$$
$$\mathbb{E}\left(I(r\geqslant s) I(R<t)\right) = \mathbb{P}(t > R\geqslant s)$$
$$
   \mathbb{E}\left( I(R < t)I( R<s)\right) = \mathbb{P}(R < \min(t,s))
$$
Hence
$$\begin{eqnarray}
   R(t,s) &=& \mathbb{E}(V^2) \left( \mathbb{P}\left(R \geqslant \max(t,s)\right) +  \mathbb{P}\left(R < \min(t,s)\right) \right) + \mu^2  \mathbb{P} \left( \max(t,s) > R \geqslant \min(t,s) \right) \\
  &=& \mathbb{E}(V^2) + \left(\mu^2 - \mathbb{E}(V^2)\right) \mathbb{P} \left( \max(t,s) > R \geqslant \min(t,s) \right)
\end{eqnarray}
$$

Comment: i solved the question but the solution my professor gave me has confused me, he has for 0≤t≤s≤1, P(r<t,r<s)=P(r<t)=1-t

Comment: i solved the question but the solution my professor gave me has confused me,i have solved it using this method and i am working through the method he used ie evaluate the 2 cases, case 1  0≤t≤s≤1 etc, he has P(r<t,r<s)=P(r<t)=1-t,and P(r≥t,r≥s)=P(r≥t)=s but for a uniform random variable it should be the other way round shouldnt it?P(r<t,r<s)=P(r<t)=t and P(r≥t,r≥s)=P(r≥s)=1-s, anyway this has me confused